# Dynamic SQL Syntax Error SQLScript SAP HANA

Tags: sql, syntax-error, dynamic-sql, hana, hana-sql-script

I have dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure.

The procedure takes three parameters:

- DimPartialName
- ColumnName
- UploadID

Here is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE "Schema"."DeletefromDIM" (In DimPartialName NVARCHAR(50), In 
IDColumnName NVARCHAR(50), IN UploadID NVARCHAR(36) ) 
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
--DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select distinct "'|| IDColumnName ||'" from 
"Schema"."ZT.'|| DimPartialName ||'" dim
LEFT JOIN "Schema"."SourceTable" raw on 
dim."AUDIT.CREATED_ON" = raw."Audit.CREATED_ON"
where "UPLOAD_UUID" = ' || UploadID ||' ';
End;
```

And the Error:

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: "Schema"."DeletefromDIM": line 15 col 1 (at pos 520): [257] (range 3) sql syntax error exception: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "-": line 3 col 41 (at pos 214)

when I run this SQL in the console and substitute in my inputs, then it works fine:

```
select distinct "BRANDID" from "Schema"."ZT.BRAND" dim
LEFT JOIN "Schema"."SourceTable" raw on dim."AUDIT.CREATED_ON" = raw."Audit.CREATED_ON"
where "UPLOAD_UUID" = 'f889e016-1364-4aac-9536-037d932c55b5';
```

The error doesn't really make sense because not only is there no "-" at that position, there is no dash in the entire statement.

Comment: Change it to `Varchar(max)`, its error while attempting to evaluate the string `unique identifier ` data , always good idea to Print @sql to check if script is correct. In short, your script is not enclosing variable value in single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the generated SQL string by selecting it for output, like so:

```
BEGIN

        select                'select distinct "'|| IDColumnName ||'" from 
                        "Schema"."ZT.'|| DimPartialName ||'" dim
                        LEFT JOIN "Schema"."SourceTable" raw on 
                        dim."AUDIT.CREATED_ON" = raw."Audit.CREATED_ON"
                        where "UPLOAD_UUID" = ' || UploadID ||' ' as SQLTEXT from dummy;

End;
```

If you do this, you'll discover that the SQL statement generated looks like this (for input of 'X', 'Y', 'Z'):

```
select distinct "Y" from 
                    "Schema"."ZT.X" dim
                    LEFT JOIN "Schema"."SourceTable" raw on 
                    dim."AUDIT.CREATED_ON" = raw."Audit.CREATED_ON"
                    where "UPLOAD_UUID" = Z
```

Notice how the `WHERE` condition `"UPLOAD_UUID" = Z` lacks single quotation marks around the `Z`.

Changing the statement to

```
BEGIN

    execute immediate 
                  'select distinct "'|| :IDColumnName ||'" ' 
               || 'from '
               || '"Schema"."ZT.'|| :DimPartialName ||'" dim '
               || 'LEFT JOIN "Schema"."SourceTable" raw on '
               || 'dim."AUDIT.CREATED_ON" = raw."Audit.CREATED_ON" '
               || 'where "UPLOAD_UUID" = ''' || :UploadID ||''' ';

END;
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could print dynamic SQL. Part of the reason I find SQL so hard to debug is because I have no console that I can print to, but I guess there sort of is.